# React redux - object is possibly 'undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux

I'm getting a Typescript error that an object I'm using from Redux is possibly undefined, even though I don't say it's type can be undefined or set it to undefined anywhere.

**/redux/globalSettings/actions.ts**

```
import { ADD_GLOBAL_SETTINGS } from '../../config/actions';
import { AddGlobalSettingsAction } from './types';
import GlobalSettings from '../../typings/contentful/GlobalSettings';

export const addGlobalSettings = (payload: GlobalSettings): AddGlobalSettingsAction => ({
  type: ADD_GLOBAL_SETTINGS,
  payload,
});
```

**/redux/globalSettings/reducers.ts**

```
import { ADD_GLOBAL_SETTINGS } from '../../config/actions';
import { GlobalSettingsAction, GlobalSettingsState } from './types';

export default (
  state: GlobalSettingsState,
  action: GlobalSettingsAction,
): GlobalSettingsState  => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_GLOBAL_SETTINGS:
      return { ...action.payload };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

**/redux/globalSettings/types.ts**

```
import { ADD_GLOBAL_SETTINGS } from '../../config/actions';
import GlobalSettings from '../../typings/contentful/GlobalSettings';

export type GlobalSettingsState = GlobalSettings;

export interface AddGlobalSettingsAction {
  payload: GlobalSettings;
  type: typeof ADD_GLOBAL_SETTINGS;
}

export type GlobalSettingsAction = AddGlobalSettingsAction;
```

**/redux/reducer.ts**

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import globalSettings from './globalSettings/reducers';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  globalSettings,
});

export type StoreState = ReturnType<typeof rootReducer>;

export default rootReducer;
```

**/redux/index.ts**

```
import { applyMiddleware, createStore } from 'redux';
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension/developmentOnly';
import rootReducer, { StoreState } from './reducer';

export const initialiseStore = (
  initialState: StoreState,
) => createStore(
  rootReducer,
  initialState,
  composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware()),
);
```

I use this in my NextJS project by using `next-redux-wrapper` NPM package (a React HOC) on the export of my `_app.js` page like so:

```
export default withRedux(initialiseStore)(Page);
```

I get an error in /redux/reducer.ts of: `Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'GlobalSettings'`.

If I use the `globalSettings` redux state on one of my pages, accessing `globalSettings.fields.navigationLinks` creates another Typescript error that `globalSettings` might be undefined.

Driving me crazy, what have I done wrong here?

Comment: @AluanHaddad Nothing relevant is marked as undefined or optionally undefined in there. I could post that file but based on this response, probably no point.

Comment: Ok. Then you're probably passing through a partial type inside of one of the partial somewhere in a library but  that's just a guess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error

> I get an error in /redux/reducer.ts of: Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'GlobalSettings'

relates to how you defined reducer

It should be

```
const initalState: GlobalSettingsState = {/* valid inital state */};

export default (
    state: GlobalSettingsState | undefined = initalState,
    action: GlobalSettingsAction,
): GlobalSettingsState  => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case ADD_GLOBAL_SETTINGS:
            return { ...action.payload };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Reducer can be called with state set to undefined (to initialize state). So `state` argument should has `undefined` as possible value.

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue similar to this when I added `extraReducers` to a pre-existing `reducers` dict (using `redux-toolkit`). All of my `reducers` previously fine had TypeScript errors around either

`WritableDraft<WritableDraft<MySlice>>`

and/or

`Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'WritableDraft<MySlice>'`

It turns out one of my `reducers` was returning undefined instead of `state` (`redux-toolkit` uses `immer` so I guess it may work despite `return undefined`).

Returning `state` fixed it.